# Animation of man sent to kill future omnipotent leader

Tags: identify-this-movie

Cartoon movie where animation reminded me of the old Hobbit movie.  It was about a powerful being who turned evil.  There was a scene where humans were being killed almost in conveyor-belt fashion.

In the past he had realized that he would turn corrupt, so put someone to sleep and then forced himself to forget about doing so.  His goal was to have the man awake and kill his future (now current) self.

One scene was where they were having a conversation and the omnipotent denies that he ever did such a thing.

Sorry I know not much to go on.  I remember renting it in a video store around 1985 if that helps.  Doing a few searches of popular animations didn't yield much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Gandahar](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0095525/), (1988), by René Laloux.

> An evil force from 1000 years in the future begins to destroy an
>   idyllic paradise, where the citizens are in perfect harmony with
>   nature.

The full movie is on [Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w4D4jMOiuPg) in eight parts.  The English version, renamed **Light Years**, is there too, but according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light_Years_(film)) it does not contain most of Gabriel Yared's soundtrack for the original version of the film.

Comment: Hey thanks for your response.  it could be, but from the brief scan I didn't see a pivotal scene I remember.  I will watch the whole thing and let you know.

Comment: @RobertLugg So what was the verdict?

Comment: Well, it was so different than what I remember.  But there was enough similarity that it absolutely had to be it.